# Powershell script to remove version history in sharepoint

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

Apologies if this is a super simple one, I am not great with PowerShell, just muddling through. Essentially I need to be able to delete all version history in a specific SharePoint site and have created the below but it is still throwing various errors, can someone help explain how I've gone wrong:

```
# Import SharePoint PnP PowerShell module
Import-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline -Force

# Connect to SharePoint Online
$siteUrl = "Sharepoint site/sites/specific site"
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -interactive

# Get all files in the document library
$libraryName = "Documents"
$files = Get-PnPListItem -List $libraryName -Fields File

# Iterate through each file, check it in and discard versions
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $fileItem = $file.FieldValues.File
    $fileUrl = $fileItem.ServerRelativeUrl
    
    # Check if the file is checked out
    if ($fileItem.CheckOutType -ne "None") {
        # Check in the file
        CheckIn-PnPFile -Url $fileUrl -Comment "Checked in by script"
    }

    # Discard all versions of the file
    Set-PnPTenantSite -Url $siteUrl -LibraryPath $fileUrl -NoScriptSite -RemoveDeletedItems -RecycleBinCleanup -SkipRecycleBin -Force
}

# Disconnect from SharePoint Online
Disconnect-PnPOnline
```

Comment: Hi Mathias, thankyou for this. Apologies I now get this error: Connect-PnPOnline : For security reasons DTD is prohibited in this XML document. To enable DTD processing set the DtdProcessing property on XmlReaderSettings to Parse and pass the settings 
into XmlReader.Create method.